# backbone and javascript: upload and store the image data in GAE datastore?

Tags: javascript, python, image, google-app-engine, backbone.js

I have been searching through wherever possible but got no help at all for this question.
I am working on a small program using python GAE with backbone javascript, I want the user can create a new book with a html form given below and store the new book in the GAE datastore, the form contains strings and an image.

```
<form>
    <div><label>Title:</label> <input type="text" id="title" name="book_title" ></div>
<div><label>Author:</label> <input type="text" id="author" name="book_author" ></div>     
    <div><label>Picture:</label> <input id="image" type="file" class="upload" name="img" /></div>
    <div><img id="img_preview" src="#" alt="image" ></img></div>
    <div><button class="create_book">Create Book</button></div>
 </form>
```

selecting a book picture from the local file system is handled by displayPicture method in order to load a thumbnail image on the page for preview.

clicking "Create Book" button event is handled by the createBook method in javascript file:

```
event:{
    "click .create_book": "createBook" ,
    "change .upload": "displayPicture",
     ......
},
createBook:function(){
    this.model.set({
         title: $('#title').val(),
         author: $('#author').val(),
         image: this.pictureFile.name
    });
    ......
    app.bookList.create(this.model,{wait:true,
          success:function(){
                alert("A new book has been created!");
          }
    });
    return false;
  },  
    ......
    displayPicture: function(evt){
          var files = evt.target.files;
          if(files){
              this.pictureFile = files[0];
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = function(){
                   $('#img_preview').attr('src',reader.result).width(200).height(200);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(this.pictureFile);
     },
     ..........
```

at the python server end:

```
      class Book(db.Model):
         title = db.StringProperty()
         author = db.StringProperty()
         image = db.BlobProperty()

      class createBook(webapp.RequestHandler):
          def post(self):
              book = Book()
              book.title = self.request.get("title")
              book.author = self.request.get("author")  
              book.image = db.Blob(self.request.get("image"))
              book.put()
          ......

        application = webapp.WSGIApplication( 
        [
        .....
        ('/books/?',createBook)
        ],
        debug=Ture
        )
```

I can only display the thumbnail picture on the page for preview, but fail to create the new book, the line "app.bookList.create(...)" does send a POST request to the python server end, and the request is handled by the "createBook" method, but Firebug shows the "self.request.get("title"/"author"/"image")" lines are just an empty string, which means the content of the form is not retrieved from the Http request properly.
can you tell what are the problems in my code snippet ? thanks for your help.

Comment: can anyone tell me,is this a question that has no solution at all, or did I ask a wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is likely that you are passing a model in to `create`.  From the Backbone docs:

> create collection.create(attributes, [options])
>
> Convenience to create a new instance of a model within a collection.

`create` isn't expecting a model, because it creates a model; what it's expecting is a raw JSON object (eg. `{foo: bar}`).

****EDIT**** Actually, that's incorrect, create can accept an (un-saved) model; leaving the next few lines here any way so this doesn't get too confusing.

You *could* fix this by doing:

```
app.bookList.create(this.model.attributes, {wait:true,
```

or:

```
app.bookList.create(this.model.toJSON(), {wait:true,
```

but really you don't need to use `create` at all because you don't need to create a model (you already have one).  What you (probably) want to do is `add` the model you have to the collection:

```
app.bookList.add(this.model)
```

and then sync it with the server separately:

```
this.model.save(null, {wait:true,
      success:function(){
            alert("A new book has been created!");
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi machineghost, I have tried your first two solutions, "this.model.attributes" and "this.model.toJSON()", and they don't make any difference, self.request.get('title') will get an empty string "str:".

Comment: However,  the line "app.bookList.create(this.model....)" does seem to pass the new book's attributes to the server end: debugging with the expression, use instead of "self.request.get", but  "self.request.body" will get "str:{"title": "a book title", "author": "author name","image":"bookpicture.jpg"}, why?

Comment: I just read the backbone docs, fro "create collection.create(attributes, [options])", it says "The create method can accept either an attributes hash or an existing, unsaved model object", so it seems a unsaved model object can be passed in to create method.

Comment: You are absolutely right, create will accept models!  I'd never used it that way before, but I'll edit my answer accordingly.  As for why self.request.get has no data, it's because you're not doing an HTTP GET, you're doing a POST.

Comment: thanks, I actually had a look of this answered question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546825/how-to-display-an-image-in-gae-datastore, and it uses self.request.get for POST and seems working ?

Comment: Ah; I have no idea (I'm no Google App Engine expert, I've just worked with enough web frameworks to know that most have a `request.get` property with all of the HTTP GET data, and in most of them that property won't get populated on a POST *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

In the python side, you should get the data from

```
self.request.body
```

Not

```
self.request.get('xxx')
```